# Unable to get sql data into textboxes

Tags: c#, sql, database

I'm trying to get displayed three rows of a one column to three different textBoxes but so far can't figure out why all three are still blank.

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con;
    DataSet ds1;
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter da;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
        ds1 = new DataSet();
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\Gizzy\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\WindowsFormsApplication1\\WindowsFormsApplication1\\Database1.mdf1;Integrated Security=true;Connect Timeout=30";
        con.Open();
        string sql = "SELECT * From Table";
        da = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
        da.Fill(ds1, "Workers");
        NavigateRecords();
        con.Close();
    }
    private void NavigateRecords()
    {
        DataRow dRow = ds1.Tables["Workers"].Rows[0];
        textBox1.Text = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString();
        textBox2.Text = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(2).ToString();
        textBox3.Text = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(3).ToString();
    }
```

The data was added before the first run and database was shortly afterwards updated to have this data:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table] ([Worker_ID], [first_Name], [last_Name], [job_Title]) VALUES (1, N'Tomas', N'Gryzbon', N'Programmer')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table] ([Worker_ID], [first_Name], [last_Name], [job_Title]) VALUES (2, N'Radim ', N'Gryzbon', N'Manager')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table] ([Worker_ID], [first_Name], [last_Name], [job_Title]) VALUES (3, N'Jana', N'Gryzbonova', N'Secretary')
```

Just tried to do the whole project from scratch to tell you step by step how I got to the end. Since this is my first SQL database project I very likely could make some big mistake:
New WinFormProject/Add service-based database/Create DataSet and connect it with just created database/Add Table/Create all the columns/Update the database/Refresh in the Table Folder/Show Table Data/Fill the rows in/Configure Data Source with Wizard to get the Table to DataSet/ Write all the code/Add textBoxes/Run/Blank textBoxes

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Comment: I did but no matter where I put the breakpoint I still get the final result of a blank textboxes without stopping the application because of the breakpoint.

Comment: So, it never hit your breakpoint? Where did you try? on Form_Load? If Form_Load doesn't get hit, then you have a much bigger problem than databases and textboxes!

Comment: I tried it literally on every single row of the code. Are you trying to say that there might be a connectivity problem between VS and SQL?

Comment: What was in the DataSet after the Fill call?

Comment: As I mentioned sooner I can't do that it just ignores the breakpoint after Fill call. I edited the question to give you step by step preview of how I got to the end.

Comment: The event should be called...I even checked if by accident I didn't copy along with the code the Form_Load as well, but no it was created and not copied. In the event handler is all what is displayed above.

Comment: "Does happen" is more important than "Should happen".  If you can't get Form_Load to be hit, then you've got a problem that has nothing to do with databases.

Comment: It gets hit because when I add the simple MessageBox.Show("Hello");    after con.Open(); ...then it gets shown but only if I use the ConnectionString I included with the code and not use the one I got adviced below.

Answer (score 0):

This does not look correct:

```
con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\Gizzy\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\WindowsFormsApplication1\\WindowsFormsApplication1\\Database1.mdf1;Integrated Security=true;Connect Timeout=30";
```

That opens the database in your Visual Studio source folder. When you deploy your project you deploy the compiled executable, right? Not your source? In that case, you should be opening the deployed data, not your source. Unless you have modified your deployable, you can get the path to the deployed data with:

```
con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Database1.mdf1;Integrated Security=true;Connect Timeout=30";
```

Tell us the Build Action and Copy To Output Directory properties of your database.

Comment: The Build Action: Content and Copy to Output Directory is Copy Always. ConnectionString has been changed but still without a change.

Comment: “Copy Always” will replace the deployed data with that from your source every time you run it. If you are trying to save data from run to run, change it to “Copy if newer”.

Comment: Ok but all what I want to do is to get the data which is already in the Table displayed or is this related to my problem?

Comment: “The data was added before the first run and database was shortly afterwards updated”? So which is it? Was it added “before the first run” or “shortly afterwards”? Added where? To your source code or to the deployed executable? If your application has `WriteLine("Hello")`, you build and deploy your executable, then you change your source code to `WriteLine("After")`, then run your application, you realize it's still going to print “Hello”, right?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstood. By that I meant that data were inserted to the Table by the Show Table Data and afterwards updated to make sure that it has been refreshed everywhere before its first Run.